# Django model foreign key of same type

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to build a very general model that needs the flexibility of nesting. Here is a simple example.

```
Work                        Symphony No.1
  |_Work                              |_Movement 1
  |  |_Work                           |  |_Allegro
  |  |_Work                           |  |_Largo
  |                                   |
  |_Work                              |_Movement 2
     |_Work                              |_Poco Allegretto
```

What I wish I could do throws a syntax error, since Work obviously hasn't been defined it can't be a ForeignKey.

```
class Work(models.Model):
    work_name = models.CharField('Work Name', max_length=100)
    work_parent = models.ForeignKey(Work)
```

I was thinking about using a base class like this:

```
class BaseWork(models.Model):
    pass

class Work(BaseWork):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    work_parent = models.ForeignKey(BaseWork)
```

I believe that by doing that, I could make Fry his own grandfather so to speak but is there a 'correct' way to do this?

Comment: what about work_parent = models.ForeignKey('self')?

Comment: Apart from that, I would ask myself exactly what you want to achieve, since with such design you might need to implement some other data control mechanism somewhere else, as the models alone won't help you preventing making Fry his own grandfather.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Seether.

```
class Work(BaseWork):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    work_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

I am curious about whether and why this would be bad practice. Surely there must be a lot of models out there that need to be nested right? Do they hardcode the structure?

Comment: Strictly referring to this piece of code, I can see no bad practice actually. What I was telling you before is to ask yourself what do you need that nesting thing for. Keep also in mind that it's not exactly a nesting you're making here, but more likely a chain of entries which _might_ (null=True) be referencing other entries:(pk(1)->pk(5), pk(2)->null, pk(5)->pk(1)...). Circular references can be created, but not necessarily.

Comment: If you were instead talking about _subclassing_ in models, that's definitely not bad practice and would be silly thinking. Just consider you're subclassing `models.Model` every time you define a new model.